# Playstore GoogleMaps not working

Tags: android, maps

I have an app using GoogleMaps Android API 2. The maps work fine on my device as a test device when the app is exported from Eclipse but not when the app is installed from PlayStore. Additionally I get a series of warnings and errors in the Log as shown below:

08-18 10:44:18.952: I/Google Maps Android API(7756): Google Play services client version: 4323000
08-18 10:44:18.952: I/dalvikvm(7756): Could not find method gui.a, referenced from method gqh.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve static method 24934: Lgui;.a (Landroid/content/Context;)Lgrh;
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0003
08-18 10:44:18.952: E/dalvikvm(7756): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
08-18 10:44:18.952: E/dalvikvm(7756): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
08-18 10:44:18.952: E/dalvikvm(7756): Could not find class 'gpq', referenced from method gpr.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 4090 (Lgpq;) in Lgpr;
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0000
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0c in Lgpr;.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: D/dalvikvm(7756): DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0x5ea1 at 0x0a in Lgpr;.a
08-18 10:44:18.952: I/Google Maps Android API(7756): Google Play services package version: 5089030
08-18 10:44:18.962: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
08-18 10:44:18.962: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000e
08-18 10:44:18.962: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve static field 20875 (t) in Lyo;
08-18 10:44:18.962: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x62 at 0x000d
08-18 10:44:19.112: D/dalvikvm(7756): GC_CONCURRENT freed 642K, 13% free 10712K/12268K, paused  3ms+3ms, total 33ms
08-18 10:44:19.112: I/dalvikvm(7756): Failed resolving Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence; interface 4023 'Lglm;'
08-18 10:44:19.112: W/dalvikvm(7756): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;' failed
08-18 10:44:19.112: E/dalvikvm(7756): Could not find class 'com.google.android.gms.location.internal.ParcelableGeofence', referenced from method gls.a
08-18 10:44:19.112: W/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 2086 (Lcom/google/android/gms/location/internal/ParcelableGeofence;) in Lgls;
08-18 10:44:19.112: D/dalvikvm(7756): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0019